# Can't find ffmpeg folder error

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, module, ffmpeg

I am trying to download music from youtube and convert the downloaded .mp4 to .mp3 however I keep getting

> Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: ./songs/Battle-Scars.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input

Here is the code

```
var proc = new ffmpeg({ source: './songs/Battle-Scars.mp4'})
  .withAudioCodec('libmp3lame')
  .toFormat('mp3')
  .saveToFile('./songs/Battle-Scars.mp4', function(stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
  });
```

The youtube -> mp4 conversion works fine, The error is only occurring when I try to convert to mp3. I appreciate all the
 help and thanks in advance!

> Edit: Once I added ffmpeg to bash_profile it worked. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

The `~` to signify your home dir only works in your shell. Instead, try this:

```
proc.setFfmpegPath(process.env.HOME + '/local/bin/ffmpeg');
```

Comment: @JoostVunderlink  ffmpeg exited with code 1: ./songs/Battle-Scars.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input  Is the new error I am getting, any suggestions? I also updated the question with the new code

Comment: @beekeeper Sorry, I have no experience with the `ffmpeg` module.